# Changing User DSN ODBC Setting in REG is not changing in ODBC administration

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc, registry

Well I guess you could say it is.. not really sure.

Anyway I'll do my best to explain.

We are updating a server and need to update the an ODBC setting it connects to so they match. In the past I have just changed the REG setting on my pc and exported it then pushed it out with a .bat file.

The issue here is that the setting does not show under

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.IN 
or 
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources
```

Well it kinda does..

In ODBC Data Source Administration we have a User DNS named 'Metafile'. When you go to configure it the first screen it says "which SQL Server do you want to connect to?". I need to update this.

The only other configuration is that we change the defualt database which ideally wouldn't be affected with this change. It is currently set to "`Metaviewer_SQL`".

Now back to the REG editor.

Under "`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI`" there is a key for Metaviewer_SQL with a value for Server that also points to the old server. If I manually change that to the new one, export Metaviewer_SQL.reg and run that it will only change the Key in the REG editor not the ODBC setting in ODBC administration just called 'Metafile'.

How do I update this ODBC setting so that the Default Database AND the "Which SQL server do you want to connect to" are both updated? I am able to update the default database but not the other one which will break when that server goes offline.

I hope that all makes sense,  I can answer any questions or post screen shots if necessary, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Export the whole Metafile registry key (the dsn name appears as a registry key under ODBC.INI)
example:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Metafile]
"Driver"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\SQLSRV32.dll or any other odbc driver"
"Server"="sql server name goes here"
"Database"="database name goes here"
"LastUser"="sqluser goes here does it really matter?"
"Trusted_Connection"="Yes"
```

If  you execute this registry file, it will apply/change all values.
If you would like to change only the server and the database then remove all other values from the reg file. The following will change only the dsn server&db, all other values in the registry remain intact.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Metafile ]
"Server"="new sql server name goes here"
"Database"="new database name goes here"
```

Changes are reflected in odbcad32 immediately.